# General linear model or ANOVA: Can I aggregate data by group if participants change over time in a repeated measures alcohol sanitiser experiment?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, glmm

I have an experiment where one hand from 10 people (left or right) was cleaned with sanitiser. Their other hand was sampled as a control. Over the next 6 hours 5 participants hands' were sampled every hour for microorganisms, after which these 5 left. The other 5 participants (who had not been previously sampled but had been treated) were then sampled from hours 16 to 24 after sanitiser application. See figure.

I did not design the experiment or have any control over it but I'd like to know if these two groups can be treated the same or not in a mixed effects general linear model?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of the design it seems that you could combine the two groups to gain more information when modeling the correlation structure for the repeated measurements over time (i.e., you could make the assumption that the random-effects structure is the same in the two groups). However, in the fixed effects you should consider the two groups separately because of the difference in the time periods.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Playing devils advocate, why would you not consider the groups separately in both fixed and random-effects?

Comment: @HCAI I suggested considering the groups together because the sample size is rather small per group. The estimation of the correlation structure becomes more stable the more subjects you have. Hence, estimating the variance components per group separately will be more unstable.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. So using R, something like this: lmer(Concentration ~group+time+intervention + (time+intervention | participant),data=df, weights=Concentration)?

Comment: Hello Dimitris I would like to offer some bounty for this. Could you confirm please that the model you would use is indeed Concentration ~ group+time+intervention + (time+intervention | participant)? Or would you allow for a time*treatment interaction?